# to know user staying in certain page

Tags: javascript, java, web-services, spring-mvc, web-deployment

For web-development. You will know the User's footstep with session and cookies. 
but I have an different question.

If I want to know the number of users in certain page.
for example I create the  news controller. and forward the users to 
news.jsp page when they want.

maybe a certain number of people are visiting the news.jsp page at the same time.
if I want to count up the number of people who are staying in the same page.


How should I keep track users foot step.
later on I want to build an web-cite like keep track users 
mouse event and also click event and analyse users behavior.

Give me some direction 
Thank you

Comment: You can use tons of different ways for that. for example : Google Analytics API

Answer (score 0):

You can use google analytics. All you need to add is one JavaScript code.

Check here for more details:
https://moz.com/blog/absolute-beginners-guide-to-google-analytics

Comment: just want to improve programming skill